# Is there a faster solution to solve this kind of job?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, hashmap

Give a tuple below:

```
({15: None}, 
{7: None}, 
{2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 7: None, 13: None, 15: None}, 
{13: None}, 
{4: None}, 
{7: None}, 
{15: None}, 
{15: None, 4: None, 13: None, 7: None}, 
{15: None, 4: None, 7: None}, 
{7: None}, 
{4: None}, 
{4: None}, 
{4: None, 7: None}, 
{4: None})
```

Algorithm:

```
for tail in xrange(len(tupe_above), -1, -1):
   for _ in tuple_above[tail].iteritems():
      for head in xrange(0, tail):         
         if _[0] in head:
            print 'got one ...'
```

Question:

Strong feeling in my mind, there must exists a way to do this work in linear time (suppose using a higher layer dict), anyone could give me a suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, if all of your values are `None`, why aren't you using sets instead of dicts? It would be a lot less verbose, easy to read, and hard to screw up.

Comment: This is why it's faster but not yet linear time complexity.

Comment: I don't understand that last comment at all, unless you think that `x in set` is linear time. sets are implemented with hash tables, just like dicts, so they're exactly as fast (or sometimes a bit faster, because you don't waste time/cache space accessing keys you don't care about).

Comment: Anyway, it would really help if you showed a sample query with the intended output, and the code you've written that takes longer than linear time. As it is, we have to guess at what you mean, and it's even harder to guess how you've coded it and what tricks you've missed.

Comment: Thank you so much. this problem is extract from a specific enviorenment, the sub sets might duplicates many times.

Comment: Is that comment supposed to answer any of the questions I raised, or tell us whether SimonT and I guessed right at what your problem is, or …? It seems like a complete non sequitur.

Comment: After the edit: That code can't possibly work. Each `tail` is going to be an integer, from 14 to 0. So, `tail.iteritems()` is going to raise an `AttributeError`. Are you trying to iterate over `tupe_above[tail].iteritems()` maybe? And even if you fixed that, your code doesn't do anything, because inside the loop it just has a `pass`.

Comment: might not excutable, but the point is whether u could catch what i want to express?

Comment: I really can't. The algorithm doesn't seem to make any sense. If you can't describe your problem, or give us code that actually demonstrates the results, can you at least either (a) show us the desired results of a sample call, and (b) look at the two answers and tell us whether we've guessed right?

Comment: Thank you, pls see the detail description.

Comment: I give up. Your further elaborations make this even harder to understand. You're talking about substrings when there are no strings,  sorting when you're not doing any sorting (and whatever you mean by "the set", nothing appears to be sorted), etc. I've asked repeatedly for an actual sample lookup and result, or for code that actually demonstrates your problem, and you've given neither. Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for guidance.

Comment: I'm so sorry about wasting ur time. I did some reedit.

Comment: You _still_ haven't shown us the desired output, and you're _still_ showing us code that doesn't actually do what you say it does. If you can explain it in samples and source, it doesn't matter how bad your English-language description is; if you can't, then you don't have a programming problem.

Comment: ok, thank you. Why i do that might not be a programming problem. The programming problem is how I do that. :) Did u hear about suffix array  or height array involved in string processing? all sort of those stuff are non of programming problem. I just wanna to find the child/parent pair in linear time. May be no one did it to day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your "job description", but I think you want this:

```
def find_matches(tuple_of_dicts, key_to_find):
    return [d for d in tuple_of_dicts if key_to_find in d]
```

So:

```
>>> tuple_of_dicts = ({18: None}, {10: None}, {16: None, 18: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 10: None}, {16: None}, {7: None}, {10: None}, {18: None}, {16: None, 10: None, 18: None, 7: None}, {10: None, 18: None, 7: None}, {10: None}, {7: None}, {7: None}, {10: None, 7: None}, {7: None})
>>> find_matches(tuple_of_dicts, 18)
[{18: None},
 {5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 10: None, 16: None, 18: None},
 {18: None},
 {7: None, 10: None, 16: None, 18: None},
 {7: None, 10: None, 18: None}]
```

That works in linear time. If your tuple has N dicts, with an average of M members each, you walk the tuple, doing a constant-time dict lookup for each iteration, for a total of O(N).

---

But you can do even *better* than linear time, if you're going to be doing a lot of such searches.

The trick is (as it sounds like you might have suspected) to build an index dictionary, mapping each key to the indices of the dictionaries it's in, or just to the dictionaries themselves. For example:

```
>>> dict_of_dicts = {}
>>> for d in tuple_of_dicts:
...     for key in d:
...         dict_of_dicts.setdefault(key, []).append(d)
>>> def find_matches(dict_of_dicts, key_to_find):
...     return dict_of_dicts[key_to_find]
```

This requires O(N*M) time doing the setup work, and builds a dict of O(N*M) space,* but it's then a simple O(1) dict lookup for each search. So, as long as you're doing more than M searches, and you can afford the extra space, it's a huge gain.

---

* To be precise: If you have L distinct keys, M total keys, you're doing N*M lookups in a dict, N*M/L additions to the dict, and N*M appends into M/L-length lists. Since list append is amortized constant time, that's O(N*M + N*M/L + N*M) = O(N*M) setup time. Meanwhile, the dict is O(N*L) space, and each member is a list of length O(M/L), so the total space used for the lists is O(N*L * M/L) = O(N*M), and the total space for the dict and its lists is O(N*L + N*M) = O(N*M). Finally, the search just hashes the value, looks it up in the dict, and returns a reference to the M/L-length list, all of which are constant-time operations, so each search is O(1).

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` is your friend: `from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_dicts = defaultdict(list)
...
        dict_of_dicts[k].append(d)`

Comment: @hughdbrown: Using a `defaultdict` doesn't make things any simpler, or more complex, than using `setdefault`. The difference is what you get in the end: `defaultdict` gives you a dictionary that will return `[]` for an unknown key; `setdefault` one that will raise an exception. I think the latter is what you want in this case.

Comment: I'm so sorry about wasting ur time. I did some reedit.

Answer (score 1):

I will try my best to understand your question.  Are you trying to find all of the `dict`s that contain a given key (like `18`) from this tuple?

The solution that I think would be most Pythonic, and should be in linear time for this particular level of nesting, is:

```
def getDictsWithKey(dictTuple, key):
    return [d for d in dictTuple if key in d]
```